# basics of uniform distribution

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution

I have a very very basic question

Let x and y be independent, uniformly distributed random variables over [0,1].a and R are pozitive real numbers where R>a. How can I find the probability of $$\mathbb{P}\left[x>\frac{(y)(a)}{R-a}\right]?$$

We can write it as 
$$1-\mathbb{P}\left[x<\frac{ya}{R-a}\right]$$
and then compute
$$
1-\mathbb{P}\left[x<\frac{ya}{R-a}\right]
= 1-\left(\int_{y=0}^1\int_{x=0}^{x=ya/(R-a)} 1 dxdy\right)
$$$$
=1-\left( \int_0^1\frac{ya}{R-a}dy\right)
=1-\frac{a}{2(R-a)}
$$

Thank you!!

Comment: Notice that $a/(R-a)$ can have any positive value we like. Given any positive real number $q,$ let $a=q$ and $R=q+1.$ Then $a/(R-a)=q.$ Is that what you wanted, or do you want to set some other conditions on $R$ and $a$? Perhaps $R>2a$?

Comment: Thank you! no R>a is the only condition and R,a are exogenus variables

Comment: You should then consider two cases separately: $a/(R-a)\leq 1$ and $a/(R-a)>1.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is rather a comment, but unfortunately, my reputation doesn't allow me to comment. I am somehow confused, whether the provided answer is correct, as $1-\frac{a}{2(R-a)}$ can take negative values. I would personally approach very differently.

$X$ and $Y$ are independent and uniformly distributed, thus their ratio $Z = \frac{x}{y}$ has a uniform ratio distribution, see [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/UniformRatioDistribution.html). The PDF is known:
$$
f_Z(z) = 
\begin{cases}
1/2, & \text{if } 0 \le z \le 1 \\
1/(2z^2), & \text{if } z > 1 \\ 
0, & \text{otherwise}.
\end{cases}
$$

I would take it and integrate :

$$
P\biggl(\frac{X}{Y} > \frac{a}{R-a}\biggr) = \int_\frac{a}{R-a}^{\infty} f_Z(z) \ dz
$$

Answer (score 0):

This looks correct and the final answer would be $$1 - \frac{a}{2(R-a)}.$$ Another way to see that is direct:

$$
\begin{split}
\mathbb{P}\left[x>\frac{(y)(a)}{R-a}\right]
&= \int_{y=0}^{y=1} \int_{x=ya/(R-a)}^{x=1}1 dxdy \\
&= \int_0^1 \left[1 - \frac{ya}{R-a} \right]dy \\
&= 1 - \int_0^1 \frac{ya}{R-a} dy \\
&= 1 - \frac{a}{2(R-a)}.
\end{split}
$$

Of course, this argument only holds if $a/(R-a) < 1$. Otherwise, you need to substitute
$$
\max\left\{1, \frac{ya}{R-a}\right\}
$$

Comment: oh yes, I just skipped that, thank you!

Comment: @DavidK corrected, thank you